# Mesh or Nodal Analysis Problem

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

[image]

I was having an issue with the solution of this problem. I used mesh analysis with the equations, where \$i_{lamp}=i_l\$, \$i_{oven}=i_o\$, \$i_{heater}=i_h\$:

\$-120+120(i_l-i_o)=0 - (1)\$

\$-120+10(i_h-i_0)=0 - (2)\$

\$8i_o+10(i_o-i_h)+120(i_0-i_l)=0 - (3)\$

Solving these equations, I got \$i_o=30A\$, \$i_l=31A\$, \$i_h=42A\$. However, the answers did the following:
[image]

I do not understand why my analysis does not work. I also do not understand how the solutions method of assuming a 120V potential difference across the lamp and heater resistors is valid.

Comment: In your first mesh equation, you wrote the current across the lamp, I_L, is equal to I_L-I_O. Isn't it a contradictory statement to say that the current across the lamp is equal to the current across the lamp minus the current across the oven? Same for the other mesh equations as well.

Comment: Sorry, I am very confused, my first equation was -120+120(i_l-i_0)=0. How does that state i_l=i_l-i_o?

Comment: @Janson2134 Mesh analysis is based on KVL; the sum of voltages in a loop is zero. So in your first mesh equation, you are summing the voltage "drops and rises" in the loop with the battery and lamp. Going counterclockwise  in the loop like you have, you get a "voltage drop" going from the positive terminal of the battery to the negative terminal of the battery (falling down), hence -120V.

Comment: Since you've assumed the current flowing through the lamp to be from top to bottom, the +ve terminal is on top of the lamp and -ve terminal on the bottom of the lamp (since conventional current goes from higher potential to lower potential). Now the voltage across the lamp can be calculated by V_L=I_L x R_L. Again, going counterclockwise in the loop like you have, you get a "voltage rise" going from the -ve terminal of the resistor to the +ve terminal of the resistor (climbing up) , hence +V_L.

Comment: Now summing up the voltages in loop with the battery and lamp, you get -120 + V_L= -120 + (I_L x R_L)=0. Since, the sum of voltages in a loop is zero. Now notice that writing V_L as R_L(I_L - I_O) implies that the current through the lamp is the difference of the current through the lamp and the current through the oven.

Comment: To me its clear that you don't have a grasp yet on mesh analysis. There are plenty of resources online to help you understand mesh analysis. That will definitely clear up any confusions you may have on mesh analysis in the future.

Comment: I am already confident in mesh analysis. In any normal mesh question you take the difference between the current going through a branch that is common to two meshes. I can see that if you do not do this in this scenario, you get the right answer. Can you explain why in this scenario, the question is different?

Comment: I don't know of that approach. I've always seen mesh analysis as simply applying KVL. But  assuming this approach is correct given your confidence in it then it must be that you've applied it incorrectly. Based on the description of your approach that is indeed the case. Referring to the first equation, you've correctly assumed the current in the right mesh as I_O however the current on the left mesh is not I_L., its I_L + I_O. Substitute that in your equation and everything adds up.

Comment: @Jason2134 Your process was fine. You just didn't interpret the results correctly. I'll write a short note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added your loops, below.

[image]

Please do take note of something, though. \$I_{_\text{HEATER}}\ne I_{_\text{H}}\$ and \$I_{_\text{LAMP}}\ne I_{_\text{L}}\$. (It is true that \$I_{_\text{OVEN}}= I_{_\text{O}}\$, though.)

Instead, \$I_{_\text{HEATER}}= I_{_\text{H}}-I_{_\text{O}}\$ and \$I_{_\text{LAMP}}= I_{_\text{L}}-I_{_\text{O}}\$.

Your equations came up with the right results. \$I_{_\text{O}}=30\:\text{A}\$, \$I_{_\text{H}}=42\:\text{A}\$ and \$I_{_\text{L}}=31\:\text{A}\$. Nothing wrong there. You just then needed to realize (which you did when setting up the mesh in the first place) that the ***net current*** through the heater and the lamp is the difference between those loop currents.

So \$I_{_\text{HEATER}}= I_{_\text{H}}-I_{_\text{O}}=42\:\text{A}-30\:\text{A}=12\:\text{A}\$ and \$I_{_\text{LAMP}}= I_{_\text{L}}-I_{_\text{O}}=31\:\text{A}-30\:\text{A}=1\:\text{A}\$.

The mesh loop currents need to be combined when a device carries more than one loop current.